# npm ERR! git dep preparation failed

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, git-submodules

I'm trying to install a library from github using npm. I run into the following errors when using the line:

```
npm i --save --save-dev --force --legacy-peer-deps
```

I receive tons of errors such as:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /usr/local/Cellar/node/17.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/Users/raymondabid/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
```

and:

```
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path /Users/raymondabid/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneRtYsoF/node_modules/slimerjs
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
npm ERR! npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR! npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR! npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'brace-expansion'
```

Here is a link to the submodule that I am trying to install: https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew

Google doc with full stack of errors and warning when running the install: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DV1ZAWLtBtnPfKtC9fubqSv4z-ohvAUMIIv6svBWzLA/edit?usp=sharing